# Filemtime error

Tags: php

Everything works fine when I try and do this.

```
echo date("F d, Y h:i:s A",filemtime("index.php"));
```

But when I try to run a code like this.

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Chicago');
$name = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; 
$name = basename("$name", "").PHP_EOL;
echo date("F d, Y h:i:s A",filemtime("$name"));
```

I get this garbage...

```
Warning: filemtime() [function.filemtime]: stat failed for index.php in C:\xampp\htdocs\newsite  \footer.php on line 9
December 31, 1969 06:00:00 PM
```

I see no difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is the `PHP_EOL`.  Your filename `index.php` does not end in a linebreak.  Try removing the `PHP_EOL` concatenation:

```
$name = basename("$name", "").PHP_EOL;

// Change to
$name = basename($name, "");
```

By the way, you do not need to surround your variables in double quotes.

Comment: Perfect!  Would not have guessed.